# TensorFlow Importing Error in Mac @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib

Tags: macos, python-2.7, tensorflow, pip

I wasted quite a lot of time just to make *import tensorflow* work in my Mac. After solving so many issues, I finally got stuck here and could not find same problem anywhere to resolve it. If you feel it duplicate, please feel free to mark it and refer me some link where I can find solution of this problem..

Problem:

I installed tensorflow by following step by step mentioned here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac with native pip. I also took care of SIP and tensorflow got installed successfully too, but when I am trying to import tensorflow in python, I am getting this error which I could not resolved and gave up.. Here is message I am getting..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Reason: image not found


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

If you need any other info regarding same, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have NVIDA GPU on your Mac?
If not then don't use the CUDA version of the tensor flow.
Uninstall tensor flow and reinstall the CPU version of the tensor flow you will be able to bypass the error.

Comment: Nope, I don't have NVIDIA GPU, but I guess I installed CPU version of the tensorflow.. I used this as mentioned on site..

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-py2-none-any.whl

Comment: and on site, they are also saying that *pip install tensorflow* will install CPU support too.. How else I can install CPU version??

Comment: It seems like you some how installed cuda version

Comment: libcublas.so
       The cuBLAS library is an implementation of BLAS (Basic  Linear  Algebra
       Subprograms)  on  top of the NVIDIA CUDA runtime. It allows the user to
       access the computational resources of NVIDIA Graphics  Processing  Unit
       (GPU), but does not auto-parallelize across multiple GPUs.

Comment: Thanks.. Did not know about this.. But what now?? should I uninstall it and try to reinstall it again?? But again, I will follow same steps.. is there any other way around to install it??